# Get Discord channel messages in JavaScript with API without limit? [fixid]

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, api, discord

For example, Discord API to get all messages.

First, I need to request:

```
https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/<channel_id>/messages?limit=100
```

And to get more messages, I need the parameter `before=<message_id>`

Example:

```
https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/<channel_id>/messages?before=<message_id>&limit=100
```

```html
function addToCleanList(arr, key){
    if(arr[key]) return arr[key].forEach((item, index, array) => {
        if(index === array.length -1) {
            cleanList.push(item.url)
            return addToCleanList(arr, item.id)
        }
        cleanList.push(item.url)
    });
    
}

addToCleanList(database, "limit20")
console.log(cleanList)
```

This is my code successful: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-snow-uj0vst?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: Post relevant code please, with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (minimal, complete, verifiable example). Links to external websites may break in the future.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl You've got the link to the MRE page, but you're still calling it an MCVE?